# Fit image in div without blur

Tags: html, css

I have the following div that I am trying to fit an image in. Not sure If I am doing something wrong but when I fit the image it becomes extremely blurry. Is it just the image that I have ?
CSS

```
.gallery-cell {
    width: 66%  ;
    height: 500px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: rgb(202, 202, 202);
    opacity: 8;
    counter-increment: gallery-cell;
  }

img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    object-fit:fill;
    
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="gallery js-flickity" data-flickity-options='{ "wrapAround": true }'>
        <div class="gallery-cell"><img src="chevy1.jpeg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How much larger is the DIV in pixels than the width and height ratio in pixels of the image? If you resize an image more than say 30%, interpolation can happen. So if for example you have an image that is by default 300px X 300px and your DIV is say 1200px by 1200px. The computer samples pixels around the missing pixels and add it to the images display in the much larger DIV. Basically making the image *look* blurry. Here is a great article about this issue: https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/image-interpolation.htm